Is verification of pointer arithmetic less difficult than pointer modification?
I was attempting to use WP to verify memchr from musl libc, which fundamentally boils down to:
void *memchr(const void *src, int c, size_t n)
{
  const unsigned char *s = src;
  for (; n && *s != c; s++, n--);
  return n ? (void *)s : 0;
}

I had a number of problems involving anything to do with s. However, when I rewrote the function as:
void *memchr(const void *src, int c, size_t n)
{
  const unsigned char *s = src;
  size_t i = 0;
  for (; i < n && *(s + i) != c; i++);
  return (i < n) ? ((void *) s + i) : 0;
}

all of the necessary properties went through without issue. The only difference between the two is that the first version modifies s and n while the second uses pointer arithmetic on s + i.
Is there a significant difference between how Frama-C or the underlying solvers handle the two cases?

Without the properties to prove, it is hard to tell exactly what fails. However, I can already tell that, yes, in some situations it is harder to deal with this kind of code because WP misses a few axioms about pointer arithmetic: https://git.frama-c.com/pub/frama-c/-/issues/907
